# strtok() function is tokenizing the string incorrectly

Tags: c, strtok

I'm implementing pass 2 assembler in C and trying to fetch the terms of an expression using `strtok()`. The function is running inside the `while` loop correctly but it is not generating the tokens properly.

Here is the code for generating tokens:

```
char *terms[50];
char *operand="THREE-3"
char delimit[] = "+-\*";
int k = 0;
terms[k] = strtok(operand,delimit);
while(terms[k] != NULL)
{
    printf("token [%d]=%s\n",k,terms[k]);
    k++;
    terms[k]=strtok(NULL,delimit);
}
```

This is the ouput:

```
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=3
token [0]=THREE
token [1]=3
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
token [0]=THREE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the argument `operand` is not allowed to be modified and `strtok()` modifies it's first argument, so, your code causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

*Related notes:*

- `operand` is a pointer pointing to the string literal `"THREE-3"`.

  Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5

  > [...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
  >   undefined.
- for `strtok()` behavior, from chapter §7.24.5.8 (*emphasis mine*)

  > The strtok function then searches from there for a character that is contained in the
  >   current separator string. If no such character is found, the current token extends to the
  >   end of the string pointed to by s1, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null
  >   pointer. **If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character, which
  >   terminates the current token**. The strtok function saves a pointer to the following
  >   character, from which the next search for a token will start.

  which means, `strtok()` modifies it's first argument.

The simplest solution is to make `operand` an array and initialize it with the required string literal and then, pass it as the first argument to  `strtok()`.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
char *operand = "THREE-3";  // here operand points to a string literal
```

to

```
char operand[] = "THREE-3";  // here operand is an array of chars terminated by a NUL char
```

`strtok` modifies the string, and modifying string literals is undefined behaviour.